# Java gives infinity for finite sum

Tags: java, for-loop, math

I'm fairly new to Java, but have done some Android programming with it.

Now I want to sum a series using

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (float) 1/(i*i);
    }
```

The infinite series sum is finite, but beyond about 50,000 terms or so, the sum is giving as "Infinity". As long as I don't let it go for too many terms though, the series looks to be converging as expected.

Is there a problem with a data structure here, or what am I missing.

Comment: I changed it to double type in the equation and still gives Infinity. "sum" is already a double. At the 65,000th iterate it is still at the 4th decimal place, so it's not a tiny machine epsilon or something seemingly.

Comment: I guessed wrong, see @assylias' answer; it's a division by 0 thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is that `i * i` is subject to integer overflow.

In particular, when `i = 2^16` (i.e. 65536), `i*i = 2^32` which overflows to 0. And the result of `1f / 0` is `+Infinity` in Java.

If you declare `i` as a `float` you will get closer to what you expect. If you want better precision you can use a double.

Comment: iirc, `float` also returns `infinity`. A sanity check would be better in my opinion.

Comment: that's it! Thanks! I converted the `i`'s to `double` and then did the multiplication and it works. I'll accept this answer, but it seems I have to wait 5 minutes before I can do that. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Should converge to (pi^2)/6